# ASP.NET MVC 4 Database connection error on deployment

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to deploy my ASP application to a webhosting but i receive the following error

```
System.ArgumentException: Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

[ArgumentException: Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString.VerifyLocalHostAndFixup(String& host, Boolean enforceLocalHost, Boolean fixup) +907214
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) +4116
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +24
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(String connectionString, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) +150
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(String value) +59
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +4
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString) +26
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String nameOrConnectionString) +236
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String nameOrConnectionString) +281
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +327
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName() +13
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +332
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +18
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +56
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +37
   System.Linq.Queryable.OrderByDescending(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 keySelector) +66
   georgi_it2.Models.ApplicationController..ctor() +302
   georgi_it2.Controllers.HomeController..ctor() +5

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +98
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +69
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +67

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'georgi_it2.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +182
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +80
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +74
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +218
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970436
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

The connection string the company provided me is this:

```
<add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Server=(127.0.0.1);Database=DATABASENAME;uid=DBUSERNAME;pwd=DBPASSWORD;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And the one in my web.config file is the same. I have created a database already, it worked well with the default connection string on my machine.

Comment: You've tagged this question MySql, but the providerName given in the connection string is for SQL Server.  Which database are you using?

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause:

I have experienced this error when using the WebSecurity classes for authentication.  Check for an attribute class in your filters folder which is used on the account controller.  This class is used to initialize the WebSecurity classes, but has a default constructor call referencing "DefaultConnection".   Change this to the name of the connection string in your web.config's connectionstrings section (in your case, "SiteSqlServer") and it may resolve the problem.

Comment: Yes there really was a constructor referring to defaultconnection, i changed it to SiteSqlServer but still the same issue

Comment: You're using entity framework?  Could you post the EF connection string too?

Comment: isnt this the EF connection <add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Server=(127.0.0.1);Database=DATABASENAME;uid=DBUSERNAME;pwd=DBPASSWORD;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />